# Can I use exact (clock) time as an introductory phrase after "At"?

Tags: punctuation, commas, time, adverbial-phrases

As in: "At 2:15 AM, she entered the victim's bedroom carrying a knife."

Can that exact time be considered a part of an introductory phrase and split the sentence with a comma?

Also, if that could be the case, could you provide any websites where this exact structure is used? I've been looking for some examples, but the closest I could find was "On 12 July, the new law came into effect". None seem to be giving exact time in minutes as an introductory clause.

Thank you.

Comment: If the exact time turns out to be important (e.g. in a detective story), you can certainly mention it.

Comment: I'm not sure "introductory phrase" is a useful concept here. What you have is an ordinary "adverb of time" clause that's been "fronted" as an "inversion" (stylised literary device) from its default position *after* the verb in English: *She **entered** the victim's bedroom **at 2:15am** carrying a knife*. It's syntactically irrelevant whether the adverb of time specifies an *exact* time or not - syntactically, it's still the same construction if we switch to a more vague adverbial element: *She entered the bedroom **at some time last night*** (which could also be "fronted" in the same way).

Comment: ***Without wishing to make too much of it,** I'd say **this** sentence is a better example of an "introductory phrase"*. In principle, that preceding sentence also has a "fronted adverbial clause", but for reasons I wouldn't want to get bogged down in, I think "introductory phrase" describes the usage better.

Comment: @FumbleFingers, that was very helpful. Thank you!

Comment: Times are always "at" to indicate a specific time.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is perfectly fine. Personally, I would expect more sentences with exact times. Like "At 2:18, she slit the victims throat". ... "At 2:44, she was back at her own front door, and at 2:46 she took a long hot shower to remove all the blood".

Answer (score 1):

It is quite correct.  Here is a twitter user using exactly this construction

> At 2:30 am, he drops Diana off and home. At 3 am, just two miles from the Broughtons' house, two dairy workers see a car stopped at a crossroads. They look inside and find Josslyn Hay dead, kneeling in the footwell of the front passenger seat. [source](https://twitter.com/rebeccamakkai/status/1308936707132272640?s=20&t=cGEZaNt_vb8iqVGHYlGXNA)

Twitter isn't always a great example of grammatical English but in this case it is correct. There is nothing surprising about placing a time expression with "at" at the start of the sentence in an introductory phrase.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that prepositional phrase ("at 2:15 AM") is fine there. By the way, we usually don't write "AM" like that in a sentence, at least in AmE, but sometimes it occurs.

I'm not sure why you had trouble finding this construction online; I Googled "at 12:00" (with quotation marks), and the first three hits that I got (I didn't bother looking any further) all included that exact phrase:

https://www.theguardian.com/notesandqueries/query/0,,-1752,00.html
https://www.quora.com/Is-noon-12AM-or-12PM
https://vclock.com/set-alarm-for-12-00-pm/